# CSV import and auto create manufacturers

Tags: import, api, csv

I have created a script which generates CSV file. I have one problem.
The Manufacturers are coming from the data are not in Magento and practically cannot be created in advance.

Is there any way to set Magento to accept unknown manufacturer and add them automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that "manufacturer" is a product attribute and you want to create the options automatically. It isn't possible in default ImportExport. Though, my module FastSimpleImport (https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport) has this option. You first have to read the CSV file in your module/script, transfer it to a PHP array and then feed it to the importer as follows:

```
Mage::getSingleton('fastsimpleimport/import')
    ->setDropdownAttributes('manufacturer')
    ->processProductImport($data);
```

There are more options available which are not possible with default ImportExport, just read the readme.

Comment: marking this as answered, as the answer is, no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

this can also be done with [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Wiki) , the mass import tool in a 'product' oriented way.

The idea here is not to know "by advance" all manufacturers but rather , when importing products, to accept any new value for manufacturer attribute, auto populating the manufacturer list.